# Install Elementary in mb pro 2011

Tags: release-hera, macbook

Good night people,
I have a macbook pro 2011, I5 and 4 GB of memory, in the future I intend to put an SSD and 8 GB of memory.
Currently, he is with High Sierra, and I feel that he has some problems. I know that doing the upgrade greatly improves performance, the system receives security updates, but some software does not work anymore.
Can I run Elementary smoothly? In terms of the battery, it shows that the total charge is 83%, no more than that, and discharges very fast. is there anything that helps to hold the battery more? My use is for HTML, CSS and JavaScript.
Thank you

Comment: Welcome to eOS StackExchange. Sure you can install Elementary OS on your macbook pro. Reading your post however, why do you want to install Elementary OS anyway? Because you already know upgrading your macOS greatly improves performance and security, I just wonder why.

Comment: Sorry I did not express myself correctly, what I meant was that, putting a ssd and 8gb of ram the mb stops crashing. (any laptop) kkk As for security, there are already 2 versions ahead, they receive system and program updates, the version I find receives security fixes and some software I will not be able to install because I need to have a more current system version.

Comment: Generally speaking, If you have a software which depends on macOS, you should keep using the OS. Have you researched compatibility between Linux and your software? Does software manufacturer provide Linux version of it?